# Model Array in Django

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models, mongodb-query, pymongo

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to model something like:

Value: `"Field":[ { "opt1":val1, "opt2":val2}, { "opt1":val1, "opt2":val2}].`

```
class Test(models.Model):
    Name = models.TextField(required=True)
    Specialty = models.????
```

What should I write?
P.S. I'm using MongoDB as Database and PyMongo

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to model something like: "Field":[ { "opt1":val1, "opt2":val2}, { "opt1":val1, "opt2":val2}].

Django models are wrapper over a relational database. Relational database don't have multivalued fields, they use relationships instead - in this case a one to many relationship. IOW, you need another model for your options with a ForeignKey on your model ie:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(required=True)

class Option(models.Model):
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test, related_name="options")
    opt1 = models.CharField(...)
    opt2 = models.CharField(...)
```

Then you can access your options thru `test.options.XXX`, ie:

```
t = Test.objects.create(name="test")
# list existing options
print t.options.all() 
# add an option
t.options.create(opt1="foo", opt2="bar")
```

More documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#module-django.db.models.fields.related) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference)....

You can *also* use a some of the available `JSONField` implementations, but you'll loose quite a few things on the way (querying on options values - unless using PostgreSQL -, db and model level constraints etc, automagic admin and models forms etc).

Comment: Oh well... then it's another problem - and I can't help.

Answer (score 0):

first install jsonfield by using

```
pip install jsonfield
```

then

```
from jsonfield import JSONField    
data = JSONField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: and in which way can I define "opt1","opt2" etc. If you give some details on what to do it should be better because I have little knowledge of django and I'm not able to find a documentation of django+mongodb

Comment: I didn't add that I'm using Mongo. So those answer aren't aligned with the current question